# CABasicAnimation memory management

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, cabasicanimation, retaincount

I'm implementing an application in which I use some 'CABasicAnimation'. For example :

```
myAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
myAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-5.0f];
myAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:744.0f];
myAnimation.duration = t;
myAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
[myUIImageView.layer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"myAnimation"];
```

When i put this code after :

```
NSLog(@"Count : %i", myAnimation.retainCount);
```

it returns me a 1.
So I thought i would 'release' the CABasicAnimation.

But when i try to 'release' it, it fails and gives me :

"[CABasicAnimation release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8c02a00"

How to fix this error please ?

Comment: Hint: Look at the description of the [retaincount] tag.

Comment: And of course also http://whentouseretaincount.com (followed by the usual advice: whenever possible (and it's always possible on iOS), use ARC.)

Comment: I look at the official documentation, and tried some things before ask question

Comment: Do i need to remove the 'animation' from the 'layer' of the 'UIImageView' ?

Comment: @user2057209, You need to accept more answer which are helpful to you. If you do not do, it will create bad impression on answerer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is occurring because you are releasing an object that is already in an Autorelease Pool. When the pool is drained later, the object is already released, and that's when you get the error you see.

Don't release an object if you didn't create it with `alloc` or `new` or `copy`! In your example code, you don't own `myAnimation` so you don't need to release it. Period.

Don't look at `retainCount` unless you are debugging something really weird. That is all it is there for. And in most cases it won't even help you in those situations.

Comment: And i don't need to remove the 'animation' from the 'layer' of the 'UIImageView' ?